# Why does the function on my button not work?

Tags: javascript, function, button

I am writing a form to get data from boxes and do a calculation when the "Calculate" button is clicked. The button does the calculation through the function `cal()`,
but it cannot display the result in the `countfield` box. 
How the display the result in the box? Also, how the name the function with "-"?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cal()
{
   var hour = document.getElementById( "hourfield" ).value;
   var fee = document.getElementById( "feefield" ).value;
   var count = document.getElementById( "countfield" ).value;
   count = hour + fee;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following:

```
var count = document.getElementById( "countfield" ).value;
count = hour + fee;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById( "countfield" ).value = hour + fee;
```

That's because any asignment to the count variable just changes it's reference and not the field in the form. And you cannot have "-" in the name, but you can use  "_" or word "minus".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cal()
{
var hour = parseInt(document.getElementById( "hourfield" ).value);
var fee = parseInt(document.getElementById( "feefield" ).value);

document.getElementById( "countfield" ).value = hour + fee;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `count` to `countfield` like this:

```
document.getElementById("countfield").value= count;
```